# Substituted Diene Preparation from Aniline / Novel Cyclic Imine Preparation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

I have recently been studying the following mechanism recommended by another user from the following DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tet.2004.06.026. In this paper, the following mechanism is proposed (I am only focusing on  the proposed mechanism in EtOH)

---

[image: Mechanism from Published Paper]

---

Please note that the author of the paper did not show the intermediate prior to keto-enol tautomerization. This provides a valuable insight into plausible reactions that can be derived from this mechanism. Below is the intermediate prior to keto-enol tautomerization (to restore aromaticity).

---

[image: Keto Tautomer]

---

It is clear that the α-hydrogens next to the carbonyl are crucial in restoring aromaticity. If, however, these hydrogens were replaced with alkyl groups, the final product would be quite different, as outlined in the following reaction (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/ejoc.200701009):

---

[image: Published Reaction]

---

While the author of the paper did not include all of the steps of the reaction, it is clear, that the alkyl groups are preventing the restoration of aromiticity via tautomerization. I drew out a new mechanism that could be applied to substances other than phloroglucinol in one of my previous questions. I have since confirmed this using SciFinder. Here is the general mechanism:

---

[image: Mechanism]

---

It is clear that the driving force behind this type of reaction is the lone pair on the oxygen atom which can allow not very powerful electrophiles to attack the aromatic ring in a concerted fashion in which all charged intermediates are prevented by the formation of the carbonyl. Now to my question. Does this mechanism seem applicable to deprotonated aniline? This would theoretically result in the formation of a primary imine in accordance to the following theoretical mechanism I have proposed:

---

[image: Imine/Substituted Diene]

---

I would have expected to find a reaction very similar to this on SciFinder; however, I did not come across anything involving substituted anilines and alkyl halides directly. I did, however, find a very similar reaction that involved substituted nitrosobenzene instead of aniline and Grignard reagents. A very similar product is also formed with the only difference being an oxime is formed instead of an imine. Here is the DOI: https://doi.org/10.1246/bcsj.48.3727. The reaction is shown below.

---

[image: Published reaction]

---

The paper does not go into much detail about the specific mechanism about this step in the reaction (mostly steps afterward). It does not seem to me, however, that this reaction is following the same mechanism as my proposed reaction. The Grignard reagent may help deprotonate the nitrosobenzene; however, in this case, there is no longer an electrophile, so so the mechanism is probably not the same. Is there any obvious reason why this newly proposed mechanism would not work (I do not think polymerization of the product will be an issue), as I would have expected this to already have been attempted, however, it has not.

Comment: Your DOI link didn't work for me. Here is what I sent you: doi.org/10.1016/j.tet.2004.06.026 Structure 1c above has the double bond in the wrong position. It is in conjugation with the aromatic ring. (See the earlier 1c in the paper). 1d may arise by direct SN2' alkylation. In the Experimental, they evaporate solvent in vacuo. If they heated the flask, 1d may arise by Claisen rearrangement of the SN2 O-alkylation product.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that Claisen rearrangement possibility in the last question... sorry.

Comment: @user55119: The reference is: Tetrahedron 2004, 60(32), 6807-6812 (https://doi.org/10.1002/ejoc.200701009). Only abstract is available through internet, if you are not in campus computer.

Comment: @Mathew: I  was referring to the link in the second line of question that appears to have been updated. I have full access.

Comment: I now see the Claisen rearrangement! I am curious, however, because it is the second elementary step of the reaction wheater or not the reaction would proceed forwards without the Claisen rearrangement. Maybe it would be too thermodynamically unfavorable. I included a better example of the mechanism from the third picture, which does not follow a Claisen rearrangement but seems to have a similar mechanism. The only issue is that a stabilizing factor could be the keto-enol tautomerization, so I'm still not sure wheater or not this could be applied to substituted phenol and aniline as I proposed